# access hdfs outside docker swarm

Tags: hadoop, docker, docker-swarm

I have created a docker swarm configuration which consists of a namenode, datanode, resource manager, and yarn workers.  These all work well together and I can run hdfs dfs commands from any container in the swarm.  I have also exposed the port 9000 using the ports section of the yaml.  In my core-site.xml I use the hostname of the namenode from the swarm configuration.

I am unable to get a client outside of the swarm to access the cluster using the hdfs dfs commands.  I have a different core-site.xml which has the address of the host machine for the swarm.  When I run commands I get a java.io.EOFException.

Is there any way to get an external client to connect to the hadoop cluster running in docker swarm?

Comment: In addition if I switch the core-site.xml to be 0.0.0.0 instead of the host name then the external client can see the cluster, but I can't run anything on the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is resolved by following the [multihomed network instructions](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsMultihoming.html#Ensuring_HDFS_Daemons_Bind_All_Interfaces).  It seems that it appears to the namenode as though it has two network interfaces to work with.  One for the overlay network across the swarm and another from exposing the port.